# Type hinting classes or interfaces?

Tags: class, oop, interface, dependency-injection, type-hinting

Is it better to type hint classes or type hint interfaces?

If I type hint a class I could basically pass in every class with the exact same name, but maybe not with the same methods the class I'm injecting it into needs to work properly.

While with interfaces I can pass in any class (of any name) as long as the type hinted interface has been implemented.

What are the actual pros and cons of type hinting classes and interfaces?

Comment: In what scenario could you have two classes with the same name that are different ? I cannot immagine such a case.

Comment: Thus, using wrong class while type hinting is not an issue.

Comment: The general rule of thumb is code towards an interface and not towards a concrete implementation

Comment: Okay. So there is no real beneficial use for type hinting classes then?

Comment: @KidDiamond It doesn't make sense to create interfaces for classes you know will not have multiple implementations, especially if they are in the same package. In these cases, typehint the concrete class. Else you spend time adding interfaces for no benefit.

Comment: Google for `loose coupling php`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interfaces define a common vocabulary, free of any implementation details. This way, you can use methods in your code that you just know exist, without having to worry about how it's implemented. It's basically a promise. The advantage with an interface is that when you have a similar need later on, you don't have to hack some class to support different purposes or use some awkward inheritance to overwrite everything – you can just pass another class that implements the same interface.

In other words: code that takes an interface basically just says "I know this method exists, I know I can use it. Anything beyond that is not my worry." What it does with the data you pass to it, you don't have to care.

Consider the following example: you have a script that fetches something from a database and returns it to an object implementing an interface `IDataHandler` (lack of a good name). In your usual case, you have a class implementing the interface that will add some HTML around the data and then display it to the user.

But maybe sometimes you do not want to display the content to the user but you rather want to save it to a file. All it would require is another class implementing the methods of `IDataHandler` and you could pass it to the code that handles your database. You see the advantage? You have another class with the same vocabulary, and your database handling portion doesn't have to be changed a single bit.

Interfaces are great, but the solution isn't to use them everywhere, of course. If you have two tightly coupled classes and you don't see much room for any variation, it would not make sense to use an interface if you will always pass the same type of class for obvious reasons.

Another advantage of interfaces is that it aids collaboration: interfaces define how objects can communicate with each other. If you are programming some database handler class and your friend is programming a class responsible for displaying data, you could define an interface at the start so you know what methods you can use for your friend's class. This also allows other people to define a class to their needs and to pass it to your code.

It doesn't make sense to have multiple classes with the same name, so I wouldn't bother with that situation.